# Updating Flot PHP, AJAX, JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, flot

I am having some trouble updating a Flot bar chart from an Ajax request to a PHP script that returns JSON data.

The PHP script is:

```
$vars = array(
    'result' => "success",
    'msg' => AJAX_SUCCESS,
    'series' => "Group One,80,Group Two,10" 
    );
echo json_encode($vars);
```

This is returned to a variable 'series'

```
var data = [series.series];
```

This outputs to the console:

```
Group One,80,Group Two,10
```

I also have a commented out variable which is:

```
//var datatwo = [ ["Group One", 80], ["Group Two", 10] ];
```

This also outputs to the console

```
Group One,80,Group Two,10
```

The actual javascript to create the graph is

```
$.plot("#group-month-graph", [data], options);
```

The options are assigned at another location of the script.

Im trying to figure out what Im doing wrong as when I alert the returned data or output it to the console the values are identical, however the returned data will not draw the graph whereas if I use the commented out value it does.

Hope that makes sense. I have cut down the full script as I dont think that the issue lies anywhere else.

Comment: Your data format seems to be incorrect. Check https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md

Comment: This script is for the 'categories' mode of flot which uses the format data: [ ["Label", 10], ["Label",20] ]. I have tried to return my data as: 'series' => "[Group One,80],[Group Two,10]" to no effect.

Comment: You are returning a String while the plugin is expecting an Array. You should return `[["Group One",80],["Group Two",10]]`

Comment: The commented out value outputs LOG: Group One,80,Group Two,75 to the console. If I send 'series' => "[Group One,80],[Group Two,10]" this outputs LOG: ["Group One",80],["Group Two",10]

Comment: Deadlock do you know the PHP format for the array? I was trying 'series' => array(array("Group One", 80), array("Group Two", 10)) but this doesnt seem right

Comment: 'series' => array(array("Group One",80), array("Group Two",10)) outputs LOG: Group One,80,Group Two,10  which is identical to the commented value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a String while the plugin is expecting an Array. You should return `[["Group One",80],["Group Two",10]]`

Change your php series structure to:

```
$vars = array(
    'result' => "success",
    'msg' => AJAX_SUCCESS,
    'series' => array(array("Group One",80),array("Group Two",10))
);
```

Also, you should be getting the `series` array using `data` and not `[data]`

```
$.plot("#group-month-graph", data, options);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The default script has [data] in $.plot("#group-month-graph", data, options); which output the correct data using the commented out value however using the code you posted works for the JSON data. Thats fine with me. Cheers.